# sh.startBalancer(timeout, interval) meaning of parameters?

Tags: mongodb

In mongo db command sh.startBalancer(timeout, interval)
As per the doc :
timeout     integer  Milliseconds to wait.
interval    integer  Milliseconds to sleep each cycle of waiting.
Can someone please explain in detail the parameter meaning.What is default value of the same when you run sh.startBalancer() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sh.startBalancer(timeout, interval) will do 2 things:

1. Update the config.settings {_id: 'balancer'} document, to allow the balancer to run.
2. Check every 'interval' milliseconds whether the distributed lock has been acquired, indicating that the balancer is running. It will do this up until the 'timeout' milliseconds specified, at which point this method will assert.

Even if you hit the timeout, the config.settings update will remain in place with the balancer enabled.

If you are interested in looking at the code, you can run sh.startBalancer without the parenthesis and arguments, doing the same for the functions it calls. The following is for MongoDB 3.2.6:

```
> sh.startBalancer
function (timeout, interval) {
    sh.setBalancerState(true);
    sh.waitForBalancer(true, timeout, interval);
}

> sh.setBalancerState
function (onOrNot) {
    sh._getConfigDB().settings.update(
    {_id: "balancer"}, {$set: {stopped: onOrNot ? false : true}}, true);
}

> sh.waitForBalancer
function (onOrNot, timeout, interval) {

    // If we're waiting for the balancer to turn on or switch state or
    // go to a particular state
    if (onOrNot) {
        // Just wait for the balancer lock to change, can't ensure we'll ever see it
        // actually locked
        sh.waitForDLock("balancer", undefined, timeout, interval);
    } else {
        // Otherwise we need to wait until we're sure balancing stops
        sh.waitForBalancerOff(timeout, interval);
    }

}

> sh.waitForDLock
function (lockId, onOrNot, timeout, interval) {
    // Wait for balancer to be on or off
    // Can also wait for particular balancer state
    var state = onOrNot;
    var configDB = sh._getConfigDB();

    var beginTS = undefined;
    if (state == undefined) {
        var currLock = configDB.locks.findOne({_id: lockId});
        if (currLock != null)
            beginTS = currLock.ts;
    }

    var lockStateOk = function() {
        var lock = configDB.locks.findOne({_id: lockId});

        if (state == false)
            return !lock || lock.state == 0;
        if (state == true)
            return lock && lock.state == 2;
        if (state == undefined)
            return (beginTS == undefined && lock) ||
                (beginTS != undefined && (!lock || lock.ts + "" != beginTS + ""));
        else
            return lock && lock.state == state;
    };

    assert.soon(
        lockStateOk,
        "Waited too long for lock " + lockId + " to " +
            (state == true ? "lock" : (state == false ? "unlock" : "change to state " + state)),
        timeout,
        interval);
}
```